Does the power factor of a three phase full wave rectifier decrease when having a really big inductance in the load?

This is the circuit I am talking about. Now lets take two cases:

One where we have short-circuited the inductor as shown above.
One where the inductor is part of the load and has significant inductance (ωL >> R) (imagine we cut off the wire short-circuiting the inductor).

In the lab where we tested this exact circuit, my team showed that in case 1 (L = 0 mH) we have a higher power factor λ than in case 2 (ωL >> R). However, many other students had noted the opposite result and that caused confusion among us. I think that my teams' results are actually correct and I have a theory about why that is. I'm gonna present this theory here to get some more opinions (and to check if I'm absolutely wrong). Here goes:
Firstly the formula for the power factor is: λ = \$\frac{\sqrt{3}V_{LL} I_{s1,RMS} \cos(\phi_1)}{\sqrt{3}V_{LL} I_{s,RMS}} = \frac{I_{s1,RMS}}{I_{s,RMS}}\$, because \$\phi_1 = 0\$, and \$I_{s1,RMS}\$ is the RMS value of the fundamental harmonic of the input current and \$I_{s,RMS}\$ is the RMS value of the of the input current.
I simulated the circuit in LTspice and these are the two graphs I got for the input current in each of the two cases:

The green line shows the input current with L = 0 whereas the blue current the input current for ωL >> R. My theory is that because of the two "hats" in the input current without the inductor that makes the signal's harmonic content bigger than its counterpart's thus making the RMS value of the fundamental harmonic of the current bigger in that case. So if that logic makes any sense, then from the formula above we can clearly see that the power factor with L = 0 is bigger than for ωL >> R.
Also I need to add that for each of the two waveforms LTspice showed approximately the same RMS value so the denominator of the power factor stays the same. That being said I don't now how much I can trust LTspice's results.
There it is. If there is something I haven't clarified please say so. I would really appreciate any kind of help!
PS. I would have tried to calculate the coefficients in the Fourier Transform for the two cases and compare them, but I don't know how to express the signal with the "hats" arithmetically.

After simulated it, it seems that "theoretical", the power factor is greater (very lightly) for the load with a important L. But if you take into account the internal "resistor" of the L, then power factor should be lower (losses in the resistor), because there is a loss of the output voltage in it. Note also that Fourier coefficients are quasi the "same".

Could you please mention the power factors, PF, you measured in the lab? I would guess that the difference is very small, so your data would be interesting. Also, did you use special instruments to measure PF, and up to which harmonic or bandwidth? Perhaps the other team measured PF using a smaller bandwidth than your team?

@Antonio51 What is the logic for a lower power factor, PF, "because" of the loss in R? Without diodes, it is the L that causes a PF lower than 1, not the R, because of storage of energy in the (magnetic) field of L, not because of any losses in R (or L). With diodes, PF goes down because of harmonics caused by D, while the L has a minor, second order, influence.

A more useful circuit, but perhaps harder to model in Spice, is by using thyristors instead of diodes, and a different arrangement, to "regulate" the amount of AC power for the L. This results in an adjustable amount of imaginary power produced by the L, depending on the phase angle of firing the thyristors, useful to improve the power factor on large power systems. Search for SVC, Static VAR Compensator.

The "theoretical" power factor of these circuits (R-L load) is 0.955 for the 3-phase circuit. The internal impedance (real) of the bridge with the inductor is 3/pi* w* L* Ic. So, if the L is higher (for the same current in the load) ... the loss (real) of voltage is proportional to L ... and the voltage across the resistor load is lower ... so the PF is lower then "theoretical".

@Roland we measured a power factor of 0.98(that is most certainlty false) for the R-load and a power factor of 0.91 for the (R-L) load. We used a current clamp, plugged into an oscilloscope and then for the power factor: we measured $I_{s1,RMS}$, we measured $\I_{s,RMS}$\ by performing FFT in the input current and we divided them. We made sure to check the scale of the clamp and the scale of the oscilloscope beforehand so we could get the correct measurements(but still didn't lol). I would like to go back and do the same measurements but this is not possible.

Thanks for your measurement data. Seems weird. PF should be bad, ie <0.85, because of the block form deformation, while 0.98 is very good practically 1. Did you verify your setup with simple RLC loads without diodes? Did you numerically compute PF? Whenever I have time I will try

@Roland Yeah you are most likely correct about our measurements being wrong. We didn't verify our setup because the six diodes were inside a big box and we only had access to the two connecting points of each one. I really don't know where we went wrong. Looking forward to checking the data you measure.

@nikost please see my new answer for a strong indication that the power factor measurement of 0.98 and 0.91 is wrong. And a method to compute the power factor for your "two hats".

Nice logic, but you need to correlate the graph of the current with the sinus of the voltage of the phase you are measuring. So which current curve, green or blue, resembles better a sine?
My guess is that both curves are pretty much equally bad sines, so the power factors will be quite comparable. The biggest distortion is in the large parts where the current is zero. The parts where green is different from blue, both curves are close to each other.
The biggest differences between the green and blue curves is that the blue one has sharper edges, and the green one is more rounded, more smooth. So the blue curve has more energy in the higher harmonics.
So from a practical point of view, both power factors are "pretty much equally bad". From a theoretical point of view, you might perhaps find a very small difference of power factors, where I guess that the blue one, with the inductor, has a better, higher, power factor, so that the answer to your question would be: no.
Besides, I see no reason why it matters if the inductance is large or small. Either way there will be a blue and a green curve and the actual answer will be the same (yes or no).
Besides, note that with a three phase rectifier, the basic frequency of the ripple is 6 times that of the frequency of the input voltage, which is visible in the graph.

My previous answer was reasoned pretty much intuitive. I am not clever with spice, and I don't have a good lab for this, so I tried to numerically solve this problem. Here is my LibreOffice spreadsheet showing that the power factor with those rectified block shaped current cannot be close to one:

First, this shows the power factor computation with a sine voltage and a pure resistive load, and with a RC load. Power factors are 1 and 0.81.
Then, I simulated a simple block shaped load current, and a slightly more complex block shaped current.
In all cases, I compute the Root-Mean-Square of the currents. The exact power is computed with multiplying voltage and current at each of the 24 samples of the voltage sine, then add those powers (in fact energies) to arrive at the actual average power. The power factor follows as actual power divided by the product of RMS voltage and RMS current.
The yellow powers are negative, which explains why a load with C (or L) has a power factor below 1.
The green currents are parameters for those at the other rows. Playing with different values can result in a power factor lower than with the simple block (0.775) e.g. Casus 1, or higher power factor, e.g. Casus 2.
Note that a power factor is considered "good" if 0.85 or greater. The blocks created by the diodes indicate a "bad" power factor because 0.775 is way below 0.85. A power factor of 0.776 could theoretically considered better than 0.775, but both are in practice equally bad.
I leave it up to the original posters to analyze numerically the load current with the "two hats", but it is clear that the power factors will be close to 0.775, in fact so close that it might be hard to measure. I don't think that it is useful to reason with estimates to the amount of harmonics, because that would ignore the multiplication with the sine shaped voltage.
As a side note, the "big" inductance is in a DC circuit. I would recommend to add a commutation diode, "anti parallel", to avoid damage to the rectifier diodes when the power is switched off.
To recreate this or a similar spreadsheet are here the key formulae:
B2: =SIN(2*PI()*$A2/24)
D2: =$B2*C2/24
E2: =SIN(2*PI()*($A2/24 + 0.1))
B26: =SQRT(SUMSQ(B2:B25)/24)
C27: =$B26*C26
D27: =SUM(D3:D25)
C28: =D27/C27


Here is the simulation I made with microcap v12.
The straight line in "red" is the case of the switch "closed" (PF= ~ 0.945).
So, it is the case only for using the 50 Ohm in the load.
The others "ondulating" lines are the case of a inductor serial with a resistor R5.
We can see that for an R5=0 Ohm (not a "real" case), the power factor is "lightly" better then the case with no resistor added (PF= ~ 0.947 - 0.948).
The theoretical factor in this case is equal to 0.955.
It is "down" because of the voltage loss in the diodes bridge.
The others cases are lower and curves are "linearly" spaced down when R5 is higher
(from R5 = 0.5 Ohm to 2 Ohm, step=0.5 Ohm) because of "internal" impedance.
So, when R5 is very low, "Power Factor" "can" be higher for "very good" quality inductor.
In other cases, "Power Factor" is lower.


Great simulation and Microcap seems a great tool, but I don't understand how that blocky current can have a power factor near 1. Perhaps a different definition of PF. Perhaps lack of my knowledge.

I noticed your answer on https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/559701/power-factor-and-rectifiers where power factors are very low, 0.7 and less. Intuitively hard to understand why PF is very high here, very close to 1.

The load is very "light" at approximately 1 A ... And the cited post was with SCR .... where PF = 1 when it is full driven.
